# Django: get_or_create()[0] raises a multiple-return error

Tags: python, sql, django

I thought I understood that `get_or_create()` returns a tuple, therefore assigning `[0]` at the end should pick the first object in the query result. However, it raises an error like the following:

```
MultipleObjectsReturned at /admin/hr/clientcontact/add/
get() returned more than one ClientDepartment -- it returned 4!
```

(I do have 4 objects in the `ClientDepartment` model.)

Below is the code for `ClientContact` model where I used `get_or_create()[0]`.

```
class ClientContact(Person):
    def get_default_client_department():
        return ClientDepartment.objects.get_or_create()[0].id

    department = models.ForeignKey(
        'ClientDepartment',
        on_delete=models.RESTRICT,
        default=get_default_client_department,
    )

    def company(self):
        return self.department.company
```

I would appreciate any help and the explanation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add keywords in `get_or_create` function to get/create the required entry as below:

```
ClientDepartment.objects.get_or_create(name='name')[0].id
```

Provided that `name` is a `field` of `ClientDepartment` model. You can replace it with keywords based on your model.

Furthermore, `get_or_create()` is combination of `get()` and `create()`.

`get()` returns a single object. As you have not mentioned any keywords, therefore it tried to fetch all records thus throwing exception.